# How to make Popen() understand UTF-8 properly?

Tags: python

This is my code in Python:

```
[...]
proc = Popen(path, stdin=stdin, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
result = [x for x in proc.stdout.readlines()]
result = ''.join(result);
```

Everything works fine, when it's ASCII. When I'm receiving UTF-8 text in `stdout` the result is unpredictable. In most cases the output is damaged. What is wrong here?

Btw, maybe this code should be optimized somehow?

Comment: Which version of Python are you using? 2.x or 3.x?

Comment: @KennyTM I'm using Python 2.4

Comment: Have you tried `result = u''.join(result)`?

Comment: @KennyTM Now I'm getting: `UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 19: ordinal not in range(128)`

Comment: "damaged" is not useful information. Please supply a short example of (a) expected data (b) damaged data. Use `print repr(xxxx_data)` and copy/paste the output into an edited version of your question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried decoding your string, and then combining your UTF-8 strings together?  In Python 2.4+ (at least), this can be achieved with

```
result = [x.decode('utf8') for x in proc.stdout.readlines()]
```

The important point is that your lines `x` are sequences of bytes that must be interpreted as representing characters.  The `decode()` method performs this interpretation (here, the bytes are assumed to be in the UTF-8 encoding): `x.decode('utf8')` is of type `unicode`, which you can think of as "string of characters" (which is different from "string of numbers between 0 and 255 [bytes]").

Comment: @Vincenzo: Thanks.  How did you do it?  through the codecs module?

Comment: I just changed the line exactly as you suggested. And it works.

Comment: @Vincenzo: Thank you for the info.  I updated the answer so as to reflect the fact that it works with Python 2.4: I was not sure of when `.decode()` had been introduced.

Answer (score 3):

#### Short answer

Set enviornment variable `PYTHONIOENCODING`, and set the encoding in `Popen`:

```
#tst1.py
import subprocess
import sys, os

#print(sys.stdout.encoding)      #output: utf-8  this default for interactive console
os.environ['PYTHONIOENCODING'] =  'utf-8'
p = subprocess.Popen(['python', 'tst2.py'], encoding='utf-8', stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
#print(p.stdout)                                        #output: <_io.TextIOWrapper name=3 encoding='utf-8'>
#print(p.stdout.encoding, '  ', p.stderr.encoding)       #ouput: utf-8    utf-8
outs, errors = p.communicate()
print(outs, errors)
```

where `tst1.py`, runs another python script `tst2.py`, like:

```
#tst2.py
import sys

print(sys.stdout.encoding)      #output: utf-8
print('\u2e85')  #a chinese char
```

#### Long Answer

Using [`PIPE`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.PIPE), indicates that a pipe to the standard stream should be opened. A [pipe](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pipe.2.html#DESCRIPTION), is a unidirectional data channel that can be used for interprocess communication. Pipes deal with binary, and are agnostic to the encoding. Applications on each side of the pipe should have consensus on the text encoding , if it is text (read [more](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/596418/163283)).

So firstly, `stdout` of `tst2.py` should have utf-8 encoding, otherwise it raises error:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u2e85' in position 0: character maps to <undefined>
```

The streams [`sys.stdout`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.stdout) and `sys.stderr` are regular text files like those returned by the `open()` function. On Windows, non-character devices such as *pipes* and disk files use the system locale encoding (i.e. an ANSI codepage like `CP1252`). Under all platforms, you can override the character encoding by setting the [PYTHONIOENCODING](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONIOENCODING) environment variable before running the interpreter.

Secondly, `tst1.py` should know how to read from pipe, thus the `encoding='utf-8'` in `Popen`.

#### More Details

With python 3.6+, following [PEP 528](https://peps.python.org/pep-0528/), the default encoding of the *interactive console* in Windows is utf-8 (it can be changed by setting both `PYTHONIOENCODING` and [`PYTHONLEGACYWINDOWSSTDIO`](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONLEGACYWINDOWSSTDIO)). But this does not apply to pipes and redirecting.

Answer (score 1):

I run into the same issue when using [LogPipe](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/6567/redirecting-subprocesses-output-stdout-and-stderr-to-the-logging-module).

I solved this by specifying additional arguments `encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore'` to fdopen().

```
# https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/6567/redirecting-subprocesses-output-stdout-and-stderr-to-the-logging-module
class LogPipe(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        """Setup the object with a logger and a loglevel
        and start the thread
        """
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.daemon = False
        # self.level = level
        self.fdRead, self.fdWrite = os.pipe()
        self.pipeReader = os.fdopen(self.fdRead, encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore')  # set utf-8 encoding and just ignore illegal character
        self.start()

    def fileno(self):
        """Return the write file descriptor of the pipe
        """
        return self.fdWrite

    def run(self):
        """Run the thread, logging everything.
        """
        for line in iter(self.pipeReader.readline, ''):
            # vlogger.log(self.level, line.strip('\n'))
            vlogger.debug(line.strip('\n'))

        self.pipeReader.close()

    def close(self):
        """Close the write end of the pipe.
        """
        os.close(self.fdWrite)
```