# Python popen() - communicate( str.encode(encoding="utf-8", errors="ignore") ) crashes

Tags: python, python-3.x, encoding, subprocess, popen

Using Python 3.4.3 on Windows.

My script runs a little java program in console, and should get the ouput:

```
import subprocess
p1 = subprocess.Popen([ ... ], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
out, err = p1.communicate(str.encode("utf-8"))
```

This leads to a normal

> 'UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 135: character maps to < undefined>'.

Now I want to ignore errors:

```
out, err = p1.communicate(str.encode(encoding="utf-8", errors="ignore"))
```

This leads to a more interesting error I found no help for using google:

> TypeError: descriptor 'encode' of 'str' object needs an argument

So it seems that python does not even know anymore what the arguments for str.encode(...) are. The same also applies when you leave out the errors part.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33291200/13689597
hey bro I met this problem too, thanks for your detail answer.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`universal_newlines=True` enables text mode. Combined with `stdout=PIPE`, it forces decoding of the child process' output using `locale.getpreferredencoding(False)` that is not utf-8 on Windows. That is why you see `UnicodeDecodeError`.

To read the subprocess' output using utf-8 encoding, drop `universal_newlines=True`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

with Popen(r'C:\path\to\program.exe "arg 1" "arg 2"',
           stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE) as p:
    output, errors = p.communicate()
lines = output.decode('utf-8').splitlines()
```

---

`str.encode("utf-8")` is equivalent to `"utf-8".encode()`. There is no point to pass it to `.communicate()` unless you set `stdin=PIPE` and the child process  expects `b'utf-8'` bytestring as an input.

`str.encode(encoding="utf-8", errors="ignore)` has the form `klass.method(**kwargs)`. `.encode()` method expects `self` (a string object) that is why you see `TypeError`.

```
>>> str.encode("abc", encoding="utf-8", errors="ignore") #XXX don't do it
b'abc'
>>> "abc".encode(encoding="utf-8", errors="ignore")
b'abc'
```

Do not use `klass.method(obj)` instead of `obj.method()` without a good reason.

Answer (score 2):

You are not supposed to call `.encode()` on the class itself. What you probably want to do is something like

```
p1.communicate("FOOBAR".encode("utf-8"))
```

The error message you're getting means that the `encode()` function has nothing to encode, since you called it on the class, rather than on an instance (that would then be passed as the `self` parameter to `encode()`).

Comment: The problem is: if you use communicate( str.encode("utf-8") ) this works fine (as can be seen on several stackoverflow examples), except some unicode errors. But when you add the error argument or use encoding="utf-8" it breaks. Otherwise it works fine.

Comment: That's because what `std.encode("utf-8")` really does is the same as `"utf-8".encode()`, which returns... "utf-8" :) So you're actually sending the text "utf-8" to your app - I don't think that's what you wanted to do.

Answer (score 0):

If using Popen to run another Python script, then see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74607949/5169739).

The short answer is set the enviornment variable [`PYTHONIOENCODING`](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONIOENCODING), and set `encoding='utf-8'` in `Popen`.